# Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined by $x_n = ( 1 + 1/n)^n$ is a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that the sequence ${x_n}$ defined by $x_n = ( 1 + 1/n)^n$ is a convergent sequence

I've just answer :
the proof will begin by demonstrating that the sequence is :

> $1$. Monotonic increasing  that is $x_n < x_{n+1}$
>
> $2$.bounded above

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried so far?  This is a fairly commonly asked question, so I expect that a duplicate answer exists on the site.

Comment: sorry because this time is my first time join. can you help me to find duplicate answer on site. tx